# Matplotlib floating point format issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqtgraph, fann

I experience strange behaviour loading a FANN2 network from file in Python 2 while using Matplotlib or PyQtGraph simultaneously. I need to plot FANN network's MSE in real time. I will use `matplotlib` with interactivity and `while True` loop or `Thread` to update plot.

Create neural network and store to file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from fann2 import libfann
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PLOT = False

if PLOT:
    plt.show()
    axes = plt.subplot(111)

connection_rate = 1
layers = (10, 5)
activation_f = libfann.SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC_STEPWISE
ann = libfann.neural_net()
ann.create_sparse_array(connection_rate, layers)
ann.randomize_weights(-0.1, 0.1)
ann.save('my_network.ann')
```

`PLOT` flag disables plot. Output file, last line:

```
connections (connected_to_neuron, weight)=(0, -9.04591381549835205078e-02) ...
```

`...` means omitted characters. After I change `PLOT` to `True` corresponding line looks like:

```
connections (connected_to_neuron, weight)=(0, -7,55163878202438354492e-02) ...
```

This leads to errors loading saved network:

```
from fann2 import libfann
ann = libfann.neural_net()
ann.create_from_file('my_network.ann')
```

> FANN Error 4: Error reading "connection_rate" from configuration file "my_network.ann".

How to fix this? Should I change a floating point number format in Matplotlib? PyQtGraph gives same results:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from fann2 import libfann
import pyqtgraph as pg

PLOT = False

if PLOT:
pg.plot([1, 2], [3, 4], pen=None, symbol='o')

connection_rate = 1
layers = (10, 5)
activation_f = libfann.SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC_STEPWISE
ann = libfann.neural_net()
ann.create_sparse_array(connection_rate, layers)
ann.randomize_weights(-0.1, 0.1)
ann.save('my_network.ann')
```

Comment: I'd recommend asking the PyFANN developers about this; sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Add `connection_rate` in "my_network.ann" (and settings like `cascade_min_out_epochs` that FANN2 complains about):

```
connection_rate = 0.7000 {or whichever you prefer}
```

When I updated libfann to FANN2 on loading configuration file I got:

> FANN Error 3: Wrong version of configuration file, aborting read of configuration file “myfile.net”. segmentation fault

Fixed it by adding settings FANN2 complained about.